# How to configure service options after it has been added to the collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, api-design

Is there a way to configure options for a service (in this case `AddMvc`) after it has been added to the services collection? Here is an example of what I need:

Add service like normal:

```
services.AddMvc(opt =>
{
    ...
});
```

Then, later on in the code, update\add some options on the service that has already been added.

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(opt =>
{
    ...
});
```

This is an API pipeline, built using .NET Core 2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `AddJsonOptions` adds a configuration delegate, which is invoked later in time when an instance of `MvcJsonOptions` is actually built/configured. You can achieve the same result later on by adding a call to `Configure<T>` on the `IServiceCollection` itself:

```
services.AddMvc(opt =>
{
    // ...
});

// ...

services.Configure<MvcJsonOptions>(opt =>
{
    // ...
});
```

Reference: [Configure simple options with a delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-simple-options-with-a-delegate).